# Where is the line drawn between an HR complaint and a police complaint?

Tags: united-states, employment

A deputy director with the California Department of Conservation tells employees he is the angel of death, yells at employees, and tells employees they better run when they see him. At what point is this no longer an HR issue but law enforcement should be notified?

Comment: Depends on what HR does. They should have already been notified because of the abuse.

Comment: Sorry, not very clear to me.

Comment: [When a Mathematician's Time is Up](https://www.gocomics.com/looseparts/2017/03/14)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I can't see an answer making an exhaustive case of delineating between HR issue and police issue, nor does this seem like appropriate place for it

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is: as soon if anything illegal happens law enforcement could be contacted. This could be (but not limited to)

- Constant, repeated, structural verbal abuse (HR should be contacted first IMO)
- physical violence of any sort (no need to go to HR first)
- Serious death threats (no need to go to HR first)

It sound like this should already have been flagged with HR. If nothing happens, maybe California has a special place where whisttleblowers can go to? Such a place exists in my country. It might help if you are dealing with a sort of cover up